# Does socket recv() force a flush of socket send() buffers?

Tags: sockets, tcp

In my application, I send two small messages to the server (a memcached-like service). In Python-like pseudocode, this looks like:

```
sock.send("add some-key 0")
ignored = sock.recv(...)
sock.send("incr some-key 1")
new_value = sock.recv(...)
```

Since the server supports fire-and-forget-style writes, I can optimize this code to look more like:

```
sock.send("add some-key 0 noreply")
sock.send("incr some-key 1")
new_value = sock.recv(...)
```

However, this takes significantly longer -- an average of 40ms for this version, versus an average of under 1ms for the former.

Furthermore, I've noticed that if I create the socket with `TCP_NODELAY`, thus disabling Nagle's algorithm, the timings for the second snippet are similar to the first. This suggests that the delay is happening between the two `send()`s (the "write-write-read" problem).

I'm reasonably convinced that disabling Nagle is the right move for my application -- I have a fairly high volume of fairly small writes that must be handled with as little latency as possible -- but I'm not sure why it wasn't necessary in the first example. Does `recv()` force the kernel to send any buffered writes? I suspect this is true, but I haven't been able to find documentation to that effect anywhere.

(Note this is Linux 2.6.32 and glibc 2.12 with Python 2.6.8, in case any of that has any bearing on the answer)

Comment: It seems to be unlikely -- you are calling recv in the second example too. What is actual size of the examples? Is it possible, that you are hitting the TCP buffer size by sending the "add some-key 0 noreply", but not by sending "add some-key 0" ? Also, wireshark dump would help

Comment: `recv` should not flush. If it does I'd consider that a quality problem with the kernel because it makes it impossible to use Nagling in this scenario (provided that you wanted it which is not for the kernel to decide).

Comment: @rkapl Damn, that's a really good point I utterly missed :\ I'm not sure if I can easily get a wireshark dump, but I can try. I'm still curious to hear others' (especially experts) opinions on what might be going on.

Comment: @usr: Actually, I think it should.  If an app sends data, the OS might buffer it to join with a subsequent write.  If the app then tells the OS to _blocking recieve_ the OS immediately knows that the app isn't going to be sending any more data until it receives something, and it should therefore send the outgoing data immediately.  (Well, assuming single threaded, which may not be a safe assumption...)

Comment: @MooingDuck some protocols are sending full-duplex. I'm not a proponent of the kernel doing a lot of magic. I actually think nagling should not be implemented in the kernel in the first place. Could be in a user-mode library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does recv() force the kernel to send any buffered writes?

No. The two directions of a TCP connection are completely independent.

The Nagle algorithm delays sending a packet for up to I think 200ms under certain circumstances so that it can be coalesced with subsequent writes. That's what you're seeing, and when you disable Nagle it stops happening.

> I suspect this is true

It isn't.

> but I haven't been able to find documentation to that effect anywhere.

You won't.

Comment: Thanks. Any theory on why my first sample didn't exhibit the Nagle problem?

Comment: Your first sample does everything right -- you send everything you can in each call to write. Your second sample does not -- you send a small amount of data when you could send a large amount of data.